# Variation of Computer Modern font in IEEEtran document class

Tags: ieeetran, computer-modern, mathbb

This is really a mystery for me -- how to make up the following equations, which are very common in IEEEtran:
[image: Exampe1]

Another example:

[image]

They look quite similar to the standard CM font in latex, but not exactly the same. I tried many other fond packages but none of them produce like that. Especially, the `\mathbb{}` seems different and other symbols look more compact.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The formulas are in Computer Modern. The blackboard bold type is not the AMS one.

Comment: Thanks! However in some paper (for instance http://www.psi.toronto.edu/pubs/2001/frey2001factor.pdf ), the math expressions seem bigger and wider. Any hint on which package to use for that?

Comment: I’m not sure about “bigger and wider”. What I can say is that the paper is poorly typeset with math fonts in bitmap format and, what’s worse, visually incompatible with the text font.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was just curious about how they made those equations look so differently. I will simply stick with the usual CM font -- thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The screenshots you posted feature the following fonts

- text font: `Times Roman` (upright) [default for `IEEEtran` document class]
- math font: `Computer Modern` [also the default]
- "blackboard bold": either `Fourier` or `Boondox`

As @egreg has already pointed out in a comment, this font combination is anything but successful. In fact, the combination is poor. Compare, e.g., the form of the digit `1` in the equations with the form on the final line of text. Observe that Computer Modern almost looks "spindly" and thin next to the darker, less contrasty `Times Roman`. The serif-style `Computer Modern` font doesn't harmonize with the sans-serif blackboard-bold letters `E` and `P`.

[image]

---

I you *must* use the `IEEEtran` document class -- and hence are stuck with Times Roman as the main text font -- I suggest you *not* specify the document class option `times`; doing so will load the obsolete `txfonts` package. Instead, load the packages `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` via `\usepackage` statements.

[image]

---

For the sake of completeness, here's the code that generated the screenshots shown above.

```
\documentclass[conf]{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage[bb=fourier]{mathalfa} % or 'boondox'?
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}
\[
P_{ij}=\frac{5}{n(m+n)}\sum_{l=0}^{m-1} \frac{1}{5+l} \mathbb{P}(L=l)
\]
where $L$ is the number of agents in $\mathcal{M}$ that land in the neighborhood of $i$. The summation is just
\[
\sum_{l=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{5+l}\mathbb{P}(L=l)=\mathbb{E}[1/(5+L)]
\]
which is clearly upper bounded by 1, so \dots
\end{document}
```